# Writing to a specific byte C#

Tags: c#, sockets, byte

Hey I write simple application which is that two players can chat with each other and basically play.

My app can do different actions according of received data type.

For example if player 1 sends message to player 2, application on player 2's client recognize that it is a message type, and fires suitable event which update the GUI.

On the other hand, if player 1 makes a move, player 2's client app recognize that it is a move type and do suitable events.

So it is buffer for data

```
Byte[] buffer = new Byte[1024];
```

Is it possible to write on `buffer[0]` type of data (1 - MSG, 2 - MV) and the rest of data to rest of bytes ? Or maybe is there the better way to implement this funcionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the BinaryReader/Writer for that.

For example:

*Sender:*

```
Byte[] buffer = new Byte[1024];

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);

writer.Write(1); // message type. (command)
writer.Write("Hi there");
writer.Write(3.1415);
```

Use the `stream.Position` to determine the length of the data written.

---

*Receiver:*

```
Byte[] buffer = new Byte[1024];

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);

int command = reader.ReadInt32();

switch(command)
{
    case 1:  // chat message
        string message = reader.ReadString();
        double whateverValue = reader.ReadDouble();
        break;

    case 2: // etc.
        break;
}
```

Comment: As a small note, `Write(string)` has "non-high" interoperability against other non-.NET systems (because it formats the strings in a particular way, prepending the string with a 7-bit-encoded length), PLUS the default encoding of `BinaryWriter` is UTF8 (this isn't a problem, is only an information). The other `Write(something)` are all very simple, so they have a very high interoperability (ok... `Write(decimal)` has very low interoperability because `decimal` is .NET only)

Answer (score 2):

What about marshaling those data? If you have, for example, a struct containing data for "move type" you could do something like:

Sender:

```
SOME_STRUCT data = new SOME_STRUCT();
int structSize = Marshal.SizeOf(data);
// you fill your struct here
var msgBytes = new Byte[1024];

IntPtr pointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(structSize);
Marshal.StructureToPtr(data, pointer, true);
Marshal.Copy(pointer, msgBytes, 0, size);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pointer);
```

Receiver:

```
SOME_STRUCT receivedData = new SOME_STRUCT();
int structSize = Marshal.SizeOf(data);
// You receive your data here
var receivedBytes = msgBytes;

GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr pointer = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
Marshal.Copy(receivedBytes, 0, pointer, (int)structSize);
```

Comment: The downside of using structs is; fixed length, strings and structs  s..ks, You need to define the first int as packettype. But.. it will work.

Comment: This is true, but they make code more mantainable and less messy if you have a lot going on with a "move" or a "message".

Comment: I do not agree with that. Using structs for serialization is way too rigid. The problem occurs when you want to serialize objects with lists etc. There are many ways to automate the use of binaryreaders/writers in objects. For example an interface that forces serialize/deserialize methods. I even prefer the `BinarySerializer` instead of structs. This only counts when the server and client are .NET. Like I said, using a struct is not bad, but it's just my opinion.